# Can characters attack flank squares without turning?

Tags: combat, opportunity-attack, adnd-2e, optional-rules, facing

Using the combat rules supplied by *Players Option: Combat and Tactics*, creatures have an orientation on the map, with flanks and a rear defined based on their orientation. My question is, can a creature attack something in its flank without turning to put it into its front? What about if the target to attack is in the rear rather than the flank?

On top of that, would the requirement to turn cause the area in a creatures rear/flank to become non-threatened areas, or do they still threaten those areas?

Answer (score 2):

According to page 7 on PO:C&T, you attack in the direction you are facing:

> Normally, characters can only attack enemies in their front spaces and gain attack bonuses when they attack an enemy's flank or rear.

Regarding turning, if it causes you to bring opponents to your rear, they get attacks of opportunity according page 13:

> Attacks of opportunity occur when a threatened character or creature ignores the enemy next to it or turns its back on a foe.

I would argue that the reverse is obvious: if you turn to face a creature, it will no longer be able to get bonuses for attacking from your flank/rear.